# How to prevent d3 from triggering drag on right click?

Tags: d3.js

I have defined some drag behaviour that works as expected as follows (code in CoffeeScript):

```
nodeDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("dragstart", (d, i) ->
    force.stop())
  .on("drag", (d, i) ->
    d.px += d3.event.dx
    d.py += d3.event.dy
    d.x += d3.event.dx
    d.y += d3.event.dy
    tick())
  .on("dragend", (d, i) -> 
    force.resume()
    d.fixed = true
    tick())

// ...

nodes = vis.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter()
    .append("g")
    // ...
    .call(nodeDrag)
```

I now try to create custom behaviour for right clicks on nodes. However, this triggers "dragstart" and "drag", i.e. after I call `e.preventDefault()` on the "contextmenu" event, the node in question is stuck to my mouse pointer and follows it around until I do another (left) click to force a release (I assume `e.preventDefault()` also causes "dragend" to never fire).

I found a brief discussion of this issue in a [thread on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/d3-js/kAjL_wP7Ru4) and a [discussion in d3's issues on Github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/391#issuecomment-3074378). However, I cannot figure out from those comments how to prevent this behaviour.

How can I not trigger dragging on right click?

Comment: In the `dragstart` event, you could check whether the right mouse button was clicked (using d3.event) and if so, not call `force.stop()`.

Comment: How can I check which mouse button was clicked in `d3.event`? All suggestions I can find like `which`, `button` and `keyCode` give me `undefined`. Apart from that: I call `force.stop()` to stop the layout algorithm while the user is dragging. So not calling it will not prevent the drag gesture from happening.

Comment: I think `d3.event` has a member `sourceEvent` or something like that which gives you access to the actual event. And yes, you would need something like `preventDefault()` as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a possibility to limit the drag gestures to left mouse button only.

It involves an additional field that records when a gesture has been initiated:

```
dragInitiated = false
```

The rest of the code is then modified to register initiation and termination of a desired drag gestures on "dragstart" and "dragend", respectively. Actions for "drag" are then only performed if a drag gestures was properly initiated.

```
nodeDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on "dragstart", (d, i) ->
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent.which == 1) # initiate on left mouse button only
      dragInitiated = true               # -> set dragInitiated to true
      force.stop()
  .on "drag", (d, i) ->
    if (dragInitiated)                   # perform only if a drag was initiated
      d.px += d3.event.dx
      d.py += d3.event.dy
      d.x += d3.event.dx
      d.y += d3.event.dy
      tick()
  .on "dragend", (d, i) ->
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent.which == 1) # only take gestures into account that
      force.resume()                     # were valid in "dragstart"
      d.fixed = true
      tick()
      dragInitiated = false              # terminate drag gesture
```

I am not sure whether this is the most elegant solution, but it does work and is not exceptionally clumsy or a big hack.

Comment: As for d3 v3.5.3, to check which button, one can use `d3.event.button`

Comment: for v3.5.6, the correct way of should be `d3.event.sourceEvent.button` instead of `d3.event.button`

Comment: Also it should be equal to 0 not 1 :)

Comment: @paradite I am using d3 version 3.5.6, and `d3.event.sourceEvent.button` resulted in an error because d3.event.sourceEvent was undefined.  But `d3.event.button` worked correctly.

Answer (score 3):

for D3 v4 see [drag.filter([filter])](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_filter)

If filter is specified, sets the filter to the specified function and returns the drag behavior. If filter is not specified, returns the current filter, which defaults.

```
drag.filter([filter])
```

**for the right click:**

`.filter(['touchstart'])`

**Filters available**

mousedown, mousemove, mouseup, dragstart, selectstart, click, touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Include a link is not bad but it may not be accessible over time.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, I had the same problem and I used the following method to make sure my `drag` only works for `left click`.

```
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()

            .on('drag', function () {

            console.log(d3.event.sourceEvent.button);

            if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button == 0){
                var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
                d3.select(this)
                        .attr('x', mouse[0])
                        .attr('y', mouse[1]);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle all listeners of drag event, you can use the code below:

```
function dragChartStart() {
    if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button !== 0) {
        console.log("not left click");
        return;
    }
    console.log("dragStart");
}

function dragChartEnd() {
    if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button !== 0) {
        console.log("not left click");
        return;
    }
    console.log("dragEnd");
}

function dragChartMove() {
    if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button !== 0) {
        console.log("not left click");
        return;
    }
    console.log("dragMove");
}

var dragBehavior = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragChartMove)
    .on("dragstart", dragChartStart)
    .on("dragend", dragChartEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually with different version of `d3` you might want to use `d3.event.which` instead of `d3.event.sourceEvent.which` to detect which mouse button you clicked.